# Creating a custom control button in WPF with image, text, mouseover/mousedown properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm still learning WPF, but I suspect I'm doing something fairly fundamentally wrong here, hoping someone can point me in the right direction....

I'm trying to build a custom control button, with an image and associated text. I've gotten this far, but setting mouseover/mousedown behaviours has stumped me a bit. I have other "button highlighted" and "button pressed" images I want to swap out on the fly for when the mouse cursor is over the button, and clicked on, respectively. Here's what I have so far...

Custom control definition (MenuButton.cs):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource",
                                typeof(ImageSource),
                                typeof(MenuButton),
                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MouseOverImageSource",
                                typeof(ImageSource),
                                typeof(MenuButton),
                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

static MenuButton()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MenuButton), 
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MenuButton)));
}

public ImageSource ImageSource
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
}

public ImageSource MouseOverImageSource
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(MouseOverImageSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MouseOverImageSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:[myProject].CustomControls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MenuButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:MenuButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="btnImage" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource [a font]}" Foreground="White" FontSize="42"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!--help!-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Example implementation (works fine when the above ControlTemplate.Triggers is removed)

```
<control:MenuButton x:Name="[a name]" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="[some text]" Click="[click event]" Margin="0,5,0,5"
                    ImageSource="[an image]"
                    MouseOverImageSource="[another image]"/>
```

I'm struggling with what to put into "`<!--help!-->`" to get this to work. My understanding is that it would be something like `<Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btnImage" Value="{TemplateBinding MouseOverImageSource}"/>` but that gives me the error: "ArgumentException: Expression type is not a valid Style value." so I must be way off.
Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be gratefully received!

-Update- I managed to get it working somewhat with:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
 <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btnImage">
  <Setter.Value>
   <BitmapImage UriSource="[direct path to image]"/>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

I'm ok with the hard-coded image path instead of using a dependency property, but it doesn't seem an ideal solution I'd be interested to know if there's a better way.

Comment: `TemplateBinding` cannot be used in a style Setter. But you can use the verbose version of TemplateBinding : `<Setter Property="Source" TargetName="btnImage" Value="{Binding Path=MouseOverImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:MenuButton}}" />`